# Use the default project template or begin from scratch?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership, visual-studio-2012

I was working with `visual studio 2008` and now i upgrade to `visual studio 2012` .

I have some questions concerning the new interface :

I create a new web application to begin my asp.net application :

1. So many organized folders `(css,scripts,contents ...etc)`

   Which is more practicable ,and working wise ? Using all these folders and files with little changes according to my requirements or just delete all of them and create my own folders and files cuz these many ready made parts may confuse the developers and the designers ?
2. Many `Config` files !!

   The usual one on the root but inside (`Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config` )

   Bundle.config and another one in the account folder ?just i want to know why the main config  has two config files !!
3. From long time i don't use the membership so i don't know if this issue belongs to the new visual studio or just as before .

   when i integrate the membership tables with my tables in the existing database on sql server 2008 through the command `aspnet_regsql` .

   i find new tables all begin with `aspnet_` prefix like (`aspnet_Membership`) but when running my application after setting the connection string with the new one like this :

   ```
   <connectionStrings>
       <clear/>
       <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=test_membership;Integrated Security=True" />
   </connectionStrings>
   ```

and register a new user i find new tables with the same structure of the previous tables which i have added with the command `aspnet_regsql` but this time with no prefix like this(`Memberships`) and my users data stored on these tables not the first one ??!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is all up to you and your team, Microsoft have made their template likely on how they see teams working, you'd have your scripts in your scripts folder, css files in css folder, etc, it's all a pretty reasonable and rational way of working.
2. The Config files are fine, they're a new way of supporting application development. Bundles.config means you can bundle scripts together (and CSS files), and so this is easier to work with when adding new scripts to your application - it's great.

   The Web.Debug.Config and Web.Release.config is actually really cool too. It means you can change, say, your connection strings between Debug and Release modes of your application, which saves you making the usual web.config changes upon server release.
3. Please read up on the .NET Membership system, that's something else
   entirely and has been around since .NET 2.0. It sounds like, if you
   wish to use this, you need to link up your users from your old
   membership tables to the .NET Membership tables.

All in all, it sounds like you need to read up on the new features of .NET 4.0 / .NET 4.5, rather than Visual Studio 2012.